# require.js with inline js

Tags: requirejs, web-analytics

I'm working on a web app that uses require.js. I'm quite new to both the app and requirejs and was wondering what the best solution might be for a problem I've run into. We have been loading third-party user analytics / tracking libraries with script tags in PHP include files. We don't use requirejs for these, because php is setting some js runtime values.

Here's an example of one such block:

```
<script src="//js.revsci.net/gateway/gw.js?csid=A08723"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        global $base_url;
        $host = parse_url( $base_url, PHP_URL_HOST );
    ?>
    if( typeof DM_cat != 'undefined' ) {
        DM_cat('Track');
        DM_tag();
    }
</script>
```

Now I agree, it's not ideal to combine js and php like this, but all the analytics code is written this way and there's a lot of it. I don't have time (or knowledge) to refactor it all the requirejs way, so I'm stuck with this structure for the time being. Now I've been asked to make these third-party scripts either 'async' or 'defer'. I'd prefer async if possible, but either would be an acceptable solution. So I want to change this:

```
<script src="//js.revsci.net/gateway/gw.js?csid=A08723"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="//js.revsci.net/gateway/gw.js?csid=A08723" defer></script>
```

My question is, how can I use Require to load the third-party script and prevent the inline javascript block from being executed until the script is loaded? From the code I've tried to write, I keep getting a "Mismatched anonymous define() module" error. I've read up on the error, but I can't make sense of it. Even if I paste in a basic example, I keep getting that error. For example, I can't even get this test code to work:

```
define(["testcode"], function(testcode){
  window.foo = "bar";
});

define(["foo"], function(){
  alert(window.foo);  // "bar"
});
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function
(testcode){   window.foo = "bar"; }
```

I don't understand this error, can anyone help to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party, but this error is caused by having 2 define statements in a single file without naming them. This is necessary to distinguish the two modules you are declaring in a single file. You need to add a name parameter like this:

```
define('Name1', ["testcode"], function(testcode){
  window.foo = "bar";
});

define('Name2', ["foo"], function(){
  alert(window.foo);  // "bar"
});
```

See these two: 
- [Documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename)
- [Related Stackoverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720646/named-module-vs-unnamed-module-in-requirejs)

Comment: yeah, a year late to the party. the site was taken down 6 months ago, haha.

Answer (score 1):

nopuck4you suggests that you add the module name as the first argument of the `define` call. **If** these modules are created inside of a `<script>` tag right inside your HTML, then that's okay. This is one of the **rare exceptions** where you can put a module name as the first argument of `define`. Actually, in this kind of situation you **have** to name the modules otherwise RequireJS cannot find them. So you'd have:

```
<script>
define("foo", ["testcode"], function(testcode){
  window.foo = "bar";
});

define("test", ["foo"], function(){
  alert(window.foo);  // "bar"
});
</script>
```

(I've assumed that the 2nd module depends on the 1st and named things accordingly. I don't know what the `testcode` thing is so I left it as is.)

**However, in general, you should not give names to modules by putting the name in the `define` call.** The RequireJS documentation is quite clear about this. If you *do* name your modules in the `define`, this may cause issues down the road due to the way RequireJS works. Things will not work, or they won't work *unless* you work around the problem. For instance, if you put modules `foo` and `bar` in `foo.js` and put their names as the first argument of `define`, RequireJS won't have any trouble figuring that module `foo` is in `foo.js` but it won't know right off the bat that `bar` is *also* in `foo.js`. *Depending in which order you load your modules*, you might have to have additional configuration telling RequireJS that `bar` is in `foo.js`.

Putting the names of your modules in the `define` calls just leads to failures, surprises, complications, etc. Don't do it. Leave the name out and let RequireJS figure it out. Then, when you optimize, let `r.js` put the names in.

Note: you may have seen some code from 3rd parties that have the module names put right into the `define`. jQuery is a prominent case. There are exceptions to what I said above but if you cannot articulate a substantial reason why you need to put the name in, then you don't need to do it. (In fact, looking at the jQuery case, I don't see a good reason to put the name in the `define` there and in my opinion they made a mistake.)