# Named module vs Unnamed module in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

We can create a module in requireJS by giving it a name:

```
define("name",[dep],function(dep) {
      // module definition
});
```

or we can create one excluding the name:

```
define([dep],function(dep) {
      // module definition
});
```

Which is the better way to create a module? I know RequireJS recommends to avoid assigning module names.

But I want to know in what scenarios we do and do not have to give a module a name. Does this affect usage? What are the pros and cons of each way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what the requirejs [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) says on the topic of named modules:

> These are normally generated by the optimization tool. You can explicitly name modules yourself, but it makes the modules less portable -- if you move the file to another directory you will need to change the name. It is normally best to avoid coding in a name for the module and just let the optimization tool burn in the module names. The optimization tool needs to add the names so that more than one module can be bundled in a file, to allow for faster loading in the browser.

But let's say you **want** your module to have a single well-known name that allows always requiring it in the same way from any other module. Do you then need to use the `define` call with a name? Not at all. You can use [`paths`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) in your configuration:

```
paths: {
   'jquery': 'external/jquery-1.9.1',
   'bootstrap': 'external/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
   'log4javascript': 'external/log4javascript',
   'jquery.bootstrap-growl': 'external/jquery.bootstrap-growl',
   'font-awesome': 'external/font-awesome'
},
```

With this configuration, jQuery can be required as `"jquery"`, Twitter Bootstrap as `"bootstrap"`, etc. The best practice is to leave calling `define` with a name to the [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

Comment: can we access the "burned in" name of the module once the module is loaded?

Comment: @AlexMills This [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28489740/1906307) covers what you are asking. Basically, if you have the special `module` module in your dependencies (e.g. `define(['module'], function (module) {...`), then you can get the module name through `module.id`. This works irrespective of how the module acquired its name.

Answer (score 11):

Off the top of my head, the only module I've seen that uses the named module method is jQuery.  Personally, I would also recommend using the unnamed module pattern.

### Named Modules

By naming a module, the name used to require is independent of its location.  Another module author could blindly require 'jquery', without knowing the modules path.  This is useful if you're developing a reusable module (outside of your project).  However, it has the drawback that (using jQuery as an example), you would need to add and entry in the `paths` config property for RequireJS to point to the correct location of the file.  Otherwise RequireJS can't find the file to load, unless it is placed in your base require directory.

### Unnamed Modules

I find these to be preferable because you can take advantage of relative require paths.  Let's say you have two files `modules/ClassA` and `modules/ClassB`.  `ClassB` can require `ClassA` using `'./ClassA'`, and the entire directory can be moved if needed.  By using an unnamed module, you also eliminate the possibility of a naming collision, unless you manage to find a way to place two files in the same directory, with the same name.