# RequireJS call to "module"

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

I'm working on a legacy app that I inherited that uses RequireJS and django-require to load many JavaScript modules. I'm somewhat new to RequireJS.

I have a define call in one of the modules

```
define([
    "module",
    "lib/jquery",
    "./scripts/*myScriptName*",
    [...]
], function(module, $, myScriptName, [...]) {
    var pr = module.prefix;
    *do something with pr*

  return myScriptName;
}
```

*"module" is a value of the literal; anything not literal starts with "my"*

I suspect "module" here refers to a *myScriptName* block in a `config` block in `requirejs.config` (this config block is a sibling to the `paths` block and `deps` block in the config):

```
{
    "config": {
        "myScriptName": {
            "prefix": "http://myhost.mydomain.tld/path/to/myScriptName",
            [...]
        },
    },
    "deps": ["path/to/my/dep"],
    "paths": {
        "lib": "path/to/my/lib",
        "jquery": "path/to/my/lib/jquery"
    }
}
```

Is this a feature of **django-require** (no tag exists), or of requirejs, and is this a standard block that is documented somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS defines a couple special modules. One of them is named `module`. It gives access to the current module as an object. For instance, you can export something by setting `module.exports` to a value. This is just one way to export things from a module. It is possible to get the module name through `module.id` and its URL through `module.uri` (yes, that's `uri`).

There is also a function `module.config()` that you can use to access the value of the field of the `config` setting in the object you pass to `require.config()`. The code currently in the question appears incorrect, it should be:

```
var pr = module.config().prefix;
```

The other special module is `require`, which just gives a reference to the function you can use to load modules.

All of this is stock RequireJS functionality documented in the [API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig).

Comment: Damn, @Louis, my eyes just ran right past that part. Thanks a bunch!